# Android Develop Application not visible in applications

Tags: android

I have make an Android app, normally it is visible in my Apps screen. But this time I can not find it. My normal steps:

- Connect Device (Real device, not the simulator)
- Debug to application
- Now the application should be visible to open in the Apps overview, but I cannot find it

When I go to settings -> Applications manager -> my app is visible.

Did I remove something from my Manifest? Any suggestions?

**Manyfest withouth classnames:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="16" android:minSdkVersion="7"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.WebPageActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <!--                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <data android:scheme="http"
                      android:host="MYDOMAIN"
                      android:pathPrefix="" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
                   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
                   <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                   </intent-filter>
                   <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Well we don't know, DID you edit your manifest?

Comment: I'll put down my Manifest, but will remove the class names

Comment: Maybe a problem with your intent-filter? You need one like this: `<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>`

Comment: I removed the one from zXing but it does not solve my issue.

Comment: Why there are 2 of `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>` in 2 different activities? That might cause the problem, I guess so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this:

```
<data android:scheme="http"
    android:host="MYDOMAIN"
    android:pathPrefix="" />
```

If commented, your app icon will appear in the launcher.

From the docs:

```
android:host
```

> Note: host name matching in the Android framework is case-sensitive, unlike the formal RFC. As a result, you should always specify host names using lowercase letters.

More in the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html), [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

That being said, I don't know what exactly is wrong with your < data> entry and why it's causing your issue - still trying to fill in the gaps in my knowledge :)

Comment: Thank you it works now, I'm not 100% sure why I needed that code. I'm only loading my website, and that triggers the zXing scanner or external scanner. First I had 1 Activity that started my WebView activity. And than it didn't cause the issue.

Comment: Great, still your question prompted me to learn about data element in intent-filters, so thanks too :)

Comment: You can, for example execute another program which is bound (by the data) to get activated when a specific url is called.